# Why do I get the value System.Data.DataRowView? c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
     Why do I get the value System.Data.DataRowView? c# + sqlserver
```

### I'm trying to add data to my table but ne system.Data.rowview and I don't know how to do it so that it doesn't come out

Why do I get the value System.Data.DataRowView? c# + sqlserver

This is where I load the items inside the Checklixbox

```
 public void Cargar_Requerimientos(string Id_CR)
        {
            cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id_CR, Requisitos, Id_RS FROM  Requerimientos WHERE Id_CR =@Id_CR  ", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id_CR", Id_CR);



            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            cn.Close();

            //DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            //dr["Requisitos"] = "Seleciona un Requisitos";
            // dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            ///////////////////////////////////////
            checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Id_RS";
            checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Requisitos";
            checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt;


    //bool state = true; 
  // for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
 //   checkedListBox1.SetItemCheckState(i, (state ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked));
            //dr = dt.NewRow();

enter code here
            try
            {
                //checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
                //dt.Columns[0].ToString();
                //checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


        }
```

here I upload the data from combobox1 to checklistbox1

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //    checkedListBox1.Enabled = false;
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == null)
                {
                    checkedListBox1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
            {
                string Id_CR = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Cargar_Requerimientos(Id_CR);
            }
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which part is the one that gives you that result? Also, if i am not mistaken, .ToString(), if not overriden, will return the type it is if it is a complex object

Comment: How do you fill the combobox? Did you set its datasource to a datatable? If yes, then SelectedItem is a DataRowView and you need to get the correct value from its columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CheckListBox does not directly support a DataSource, which is why the property is hidden from intellisence.

Usually it is correct to set the DataSource *after* setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties, to avoid multiple refresh calls, but to avoid your issue, you have to set the DataSource property first:

```
checkedListBox1.DataSource = dt;
checkedListBox1.ValueMember = "Id_RS";
checkedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Requisitos";
```